# How do I go beyond the starting index of a string slice?

Tags: rust

I have a string slice:

```
  fn my_func(s: &str) {
    let chars: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();
    let some_char = chars[5];
    //.........
  }
```

Since a string slice is basically a pointer to a string and **it's a pointer that can point to any character of a string, not necessarily the 0-th or 1st one, right?**, is there a way to go back N characters and refer to the -Nth character of the **original** string? Not the -Nth character of a slice, but of the original string.

```
  fn my_func(s: &str) {
    let chars: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();
    //let some_char2 = chars[-10]; // minus ???  

    //.........
  }
```

Provided that I know that it may cause a memory segmentation error and am fine with it.

Comment: Why would you want to or need to do this? Sure, it's *possible* but it's highly unsafe and fragile and probably undefined behavior that can break your code without notice.

Comment: You seem confused about more than one thing. `chars` is *not* a string slice, it's a slice of `char`s. It's not a pointer into `s`. `chars` contains its own slice that doesn't have any relation to `s`, so there's no reason to think that indexing it with a negative index (even supposing you *could*, which you can't because slice indices are unsigned) would do anything meaningful in relation to `s`.

Comment: @trentcl you seem to have confused what you've read in my question. I didn't say that `chars is  a string slice,`

Comment: The question itself makes sense. The code you have included in it suggests that you don't realize `chars` is a pointer to a *completely different kind of data structure* than the "original" string. If you wanted to index "backwards" from the start of `s`, you'd need to index `s` itself, not `chars`.

Answer (score 1):

> it's a pointer that can point to any character of a String, not necessarily the 0-th or 1st one, right?

Yes.

> is there a way to go back N characters and refer to -N character of an original String? Not to -Nth character of a slice, but an original String.

The slice itself retains no knowledge of whatever originally created it (which might not even be a String), it only has a pointer and a length.

> Provided that I know that it may cause memory segmentation error and am fine with it.

You can always do that with `unsafe` and raw pointers but as the name notes this is *wildly* unsafe, not just because there's no guarantees whatsoever as to where's what, but because the other segments might be mutably borrowed or any other nonsense, which land you straight into UB. A segfault is the least of your worries.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: what's the difference between unsafe and wildly unsafe?

Comment: `unsafe` is a keyword / feature, "wildly unsafe" is because I'm saying you've got good odds of screwing up completely.

Comment: Then what's the difference between "as the name notes this is wildly unsafe" and "as the name notes this is unsafe"?